# Regarding three R packages for Bayesian analysis

Tags: r, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, jags, bugs

There are several R packages for Bayesian analysis, i.e., `RBugs`, `JAGS`,`MCMCPack`. Are there any pros and cons for each of these packages?

Comment: well RBugs will interface with Win/Openbugs, which you can basically write any model you want. Jags uses the bugs language, with some nice additions, but also lacks the ability to us autoregressive priors (if you care about that), and mcmcpack is just a general suite that uses native rcode to estimate bayesian models, if you want pure generality, and don't mind bugs, then I would suggest RBugs, my 2 cents

Comment: Just for the record, [this](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Bayesian.html) CRAN Task Views provides a list and short overview of Bayesian R packages.